# How to configure bandwidth throttling for all FTP?

Tags: bandwidth

I configured bandwidth throttling for FTP by using following commands

```
sudo /sbin/tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1:0 htb default 1
sudo /sbin/tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:0 classid 1:1 htb rate 5kbps ceil 9kbps prio 0
tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dport 20 0xffff flowid 1:1
```

Then I checked with `wget` command by downloading a file from Internet. But the download speed is not changing i.e. not limiting under the 9kbps.

What should I do? I have to configure delay also? If yes, how much?